# the project target (android 2.2) was not properly loaded

Tags: android, eclipse

hi i have to create one new android project on my eclipse means am getting following error.how can i resolve this.please help me.here i have to change to layout file means doesnot display grapical layout.it is display below error.the gen file is doesnot create automatically here.

the error is display graphical layout file:

**the project target (android 2.2) was not properly loaded**

this error is display on my console window:

```
2012-09-28 12:00:33 - XcartAdmin] Android Launch!
   [2012-09-28 12:00:33 - XcartAdmin] adb is running normally.
   [2012-09-28 12:00:33 - XcartAdmin] Could not find XcartAdmin.apk!
```

Comment: just try to clean project from Project menu -- > clean..

Comment: that time the R.java file is deleted here

Comment: This link solves the problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/24566948/4295663

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible reasons behind this..

1. You may run eclipse as an administrator (just right click on eclipse - run as administrator)
2. go to window --> preferences and check whether android (in your case latest version should be 2.2) is there or not
3. select your project -> right click > source > format (after that clean your project)

Comment: android is here available only

Comment: yes yar...i had clean the project.stillnow same problem only occurred.now my R.java file is deleted after clean the project

Comment: @user1676640 that's great...:):)