# The project target (Android L (Preview)) was not properly loaded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

Recently I upgraded `Eclipse` along with `ADT plugin`s to `Android L priew`.

I have the latest Java update as well i.e. `Java 8`.

I was unable to see the layout and it displays as below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem for that is having different jre versions

I have `java 6 and 8` both installed in my system, so I uninstalled java 6 and set path for only java 8.

But remember to restart the system after setting the paths.

Now error is gone while viewing android L Preview

Answer (score 121):

Please, note this Android icon in the upper side of the screen

[image: Android icon]

This icon is in the upper side of this screen:

[image: Screen which displays the API version to render the code]

Probably it's displaying the number 20. This is the selection to use the API 20 to render the window. Change it to 19, or 20W (not 20L). It'll fix the problem.

[image: API 19 selected]

Comment: That did it for me. Can you explain why cant Android L be loaded even though I have the latest sdk installed?

Comment: Have you selected Java 7 to compile your project? Java 7 or higher is required if you are targeting the L Developer Preview, and also 
Eclipse Indigo (Version 3.7.2) or higher. Some versions of ADT are designed for use with SDK Tools r23.0.2. If you haven't already installed SDK Tools r23.0.2 into your SDK, use the Android SDK Manager to do so.

Comment: I couldn't find that icon in the Mac, so I just uninstalled the Android L and Android 4.4W packages in the SDK Manager.

Comment: Boom!  I love a simple solution.

Comment: In eclipse under Mac OS there isn't interface, no buttons, no selections... Perhaps some very well hidden submenu :) ?

Comment: Mac OSX: If you don't see the toolbar that lets you select the Android version for rendering then you are likely running Java 6. Upgrade to JDK 7 or later.

Comment: please everyone have in mind that this method is NOT a solution and the problem will persist on every new Android release as all of them require newer Java versions. Check my answer for instructions on how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 8):

You may also need to modify eclipse config to run on Java 7 Runtime.

Add this to the beginning of `eclipse.ini`

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked for me. I tried all other solutions, but after adding this it worked. I tried with jre1.8

Answer (score 8):

For anyone having the same issue:
You dont need to unistall Java 6. All you need to do is to set it correctly on Eclipse.

1. First have the JDK fot Java 8 (a.k.a Java 1.8) from:
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
2. Install it normally.
3. Go to the Eclipse Preferences and to Java -> Installed JREs
4. "Add..." -> Standard VM -> Next and search for the install path (on Mac it will be something like: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home).
5. Enter a nice name like "Java JDK 1.8" and Finish
6. Make sure to mark the new JRE as shown on the image[image]
7. Restart Eclipse for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Perfect. I missed step 7 the first time though. :3

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the issue....the 'Automatically Pick Best', picks the 'L' version of API 20 instead of the 4.x version of API 20. In my instance, I am targeting API 19 and apparently that's not compatible with the choice of "API 20: Android L (Preview)".

Sorry, this system won't let me post images yet...

Comment: If i select `API 19 | 20` it works But If i choose `API 20 L` it displays error like `Parsing Data for android-L failed
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

Answer (score 3):

You can see the following note in https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html

> Note: The Eclipse ADT plug-in requires Java 7 if your compilation
>   target is the L developer preview.

Maybe you don't have Java 7 installed?

Comment: @Kartheeks were you able to fix the issue? Any solution which worked for you?

Comment: The problem for that is having different jre versions

I have java 6 and 8 both installed in my system, so I uninstalled java 6 and set path for only java 8.

But remember to restart the system after setting the paths.

Now error is gone while viewing android L Preview

Comment: @Kartheeks it's quite a mess. Eclipse uses Java 6 by default and on OSX (not sure about other OSes) it can't run with Java 7 or 8 (gives error as described [here](http://burrsutter.blogspot.com/2013/12/eclipse-does-not-contain.html)). I installed Eclipse Mars and it works just fine now. Strangely though, on my personal MacBook it was ok with Luna but not on my office's Mac Mini.

Comment: @Sufian I am not aware of Mac OS but in windows both java 6 and java 7 can be installed manually. If you check in `Add or remove programs` in windows you can find them

Answer (score 2):

Check your JDK version. It must be JDK1.7. JDK 1.6 does not work.

Answer (score 1):

OPen SDK Manager --> Uninstall Android L (API 20,L preview),,use this if you want to resolve this error Quickly

Answer (score 0):

What I did after updating java was to set the variable system for java again

Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables.

I updated JAVA_HOME with this directory

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60

Back in eclipse, you can either:

Click Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target

Change android L for android 4.4

If you want to use android L, then change in the manifest minSdkVersion to "L"

Answer (score 0):

In my case , my current java version is 1.6.

So i run the command 'update-alternatives --config java' to change the version to java 1.7, then restart the Eclipse, the problem is fixed.

**Note:** I installed muti-java version(Java 1.6 and java 1.7)

Hope help to you.