# Parsing Data for android-21 failed unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: android, eclipse

Had the following error in Eclipse after installing Android 5.0 (SDK 21)

```
"Loading data for Android 5.0" has encountered a problem. 

Parsing Data for android-21 failed  
unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I am still facing the same problem on mac, and now as in the few answers try Java 1.8 where I found the latest version of it. Old is not available. 
I already have updated Java but I don't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to install Java v7. Android doesn't support Java v8 yet. You can get the latest Java v7 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html).

When you update your Android SDK, you **must** also update your Android Development Tools (ADT) at the same time. If you don't, you'll get all sorts of errors.

**UPDATE:** As of December 15 2014, Mac® OS X® version 10.10 is not yet supported by Android SDK. See [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I download it but at the time of installation it says it required Mac OS X 10.7.3 or later. And I have 10.10 which is latest but still its not getting install.

Comment: @NeerajMahawar: Android SDK supports _"Mac® OS X® 10.8.5 or higher, up to 10.9 (Mavericks)"_, so I guess v10.10 is not yet supported. You can see Android SDK requirements [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Comment: oh.. so what should i do now in this case. I have very urgent application has to be export from source code to sdk for launching.

Comment: @NeerajMahawar: I think you need to log a request with Google and ask them to support Mac® OS X® v10.10. There's nothing other developers, including me, can help you. Sorry.

Comment: Make sure you fire up eclipse with java version 1.7, this should solve the problem

Comment: you also need to be running a 64-bit version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

did you start eclipse with java7? check eclipse.ini to see -vm,
(like "C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/javaw.exe").

i also have the problem you said and i found eclipse is started with java6.
after i modify to use java7, there are no such fail dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the eclipse that has the wrong configuration. Check this out

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27046257/988521