# R.Java file not generated after clean the project

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I am unable to see the R.Java file in my gen folder after clean the project. I restarted Eclipse, Restarted system, changed workspace also no use, created new project but that new project also not generating R.Java file. How can I get out of this problem. This problem eats my time can any one please keep me out of this...

Comment: Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: @SweetWisherシ  nooo.. no error in console

Comment: Did you updated the SDK manager? What you changed before cleaning the project ?

Comment: I am getting this error  "Parsing Data for android-21 failed
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 " while restarting or launching eclipse

Comment: [Download jdk 1.8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26081748/2591002)

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html I installed jdk-8u25-windows-i586.exe also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67881/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-yamuna).

Comment: are you on teamviewer

Answer (score 4):

if none of above solutions worked for you. Then try this-
Basically R.java is generated to give references to all layouts and other buddies in our app. So, your IDE will not re-generate it after clean if there are '**any**' type of bugs or errors in your layouts(.xml's). Click [here](http://blog.burnayev.com/2009/11/android-developer-tip-regenerating.html) for reference. So, look deeply into your .xml's whether there are any invalid or unexpected entries there? This should work for you if updating your JDK and ADT tools didn't worked for you. Good Luck :)

Comment: @yamuna, There might not be necessarily red cross errors. Mistakes in your xml views could cause the R.java not to be generated. Go through your view files **manually** and make sure all the xml is right! Also check whether you satisfy naming conventions under _res/_ folder. This could also be a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error once and solved it by just downloading the latest jdk 1.8
Have a look on the following link:

[Android - "Parsing Data for android-21 failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474298/android-parsing-data-for-android-21-failed/26474299#26474299)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check in your drawable .. is there any drawable present with capital casing.. as name should be lower case,0-9 or _ . I too had this issue and after 2 hours i got this result. phew!

Comment: Check if you are using any project as library and added to your project, both should have same sha1 code too.

Comment: I used only paypal library no other project libs

Comment: sha1 code for both should be same means "android-support-v4.jar" should be same in both

Comment: There is no Sha1-1 for lib?

Comment: android-support-v4.jar in both project should be same so copy it paste to other one and then check!

Comment: paypal lib is just i place in libs folder and add to buildpath.. Its worked up to yesterday evening after i cleaned project R.java disapperas

Comment: Only solutions now :- Created new project and copied the files or restart Eclipse, computer and check..

Comment: What works for some is to delete the "gen" directory then clean and rebuild. Worked for many developers.

Answer (score 0):

try to download "Android SDK build-tools" package from the SDK manager without this package eclipse will not generate R.java and restart eclipse.
hope that will help

Comment: I already downloaded Android SDK build-tools and restarted yesterday. But problem not solved

Comment: You must add it as a library: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Also, I personally have to go to the project's properties -> Android -> Library section (bottom half) -> Add... -> android-support-v7-appcompat

Also, you may have to specify Project Build Target as 21 (Lollipop)..

Comment: I have target as 21 and added the appcompat lib also.. but no change

Answer (score 0):

> Parsing Data for android-21 failed Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 " while restarting or launching eclipse

You need to download latest [jdk 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).Then set java 1.8 to your eclipse and you may not get this error message.

Reference : [Android - Parsing Data for android-21 failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26474299/2591002)

Hope it helps you ツ

Comment: oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/… I installed jdk-8u25-windows-i586.exe also

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked eclipse > project > build automatically. This should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late, but i'm writing this to help those who reach to this page on having same issue.
I also got the same issue, i found some errors in my res/values/style.xml files. After fixing them, I again cleaned my project and "R" file generated :)